# Появление белой полосы при маленьких разрешениях

Tags: html

При адаптации верстки страницы http://k92816c2.beget.tech/ под мобильные устройства возникла проблема - при разрешении шириной 434px появляется белая полоса справа, причем у всех блоков страницы портфолио Как ее убрать?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Самый простой способ поиска выпадающих за экран блоков

```css
* {
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]